# Opcache causes PHP Fatal error: Class '\xa0L\xdaor\x7f' not found

Tags: php, opcache

Every now and then an image resizing script on our site will fail with the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class '\xa0L\xdaor\x7f' not found ... on line 4

The actual line 4 of the script in question is:

```
$photo = new Photo($photo_id);
```

I have no idea where the hex code `\xa0L\xdaor\x7f` in the Error log comes from. The script will run fine and it runs relatively frequently for a day or two, then it starts failing every time, with that error.

If I run `opcache_reset()`, the errors stop.

Anyone have any idea what might be causing this issue?

**UPDATE:** I got no response - so I've simply excluded this file from the opcode cache using [`opcache.blacklist_filename`](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.blacklist-filename).

Comment: Please include the constructor method for `Photo`.  Also, does the error message *always* contain `\xa0L\xdaor\x7f` or does the value change?  If it changes, you may be dealing with memory or disk corruption.

Comment: Hi Mr. Llama, I've also seen this hex code: \xa0\xfc5\x8b\xe9\x7f.  Oddly, going back a bit, I also found this: "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Photo' not found" - so at some point it got the class name correct but couldn't find it.  I can paste the code from the constructor, but it's from a custom-built ORM, and it gets pretty involved - if the issue is that it can't find the class, or corrupts the Class Name, would the constructor make any difference?  If you don't feel like banging your head against, this, I'm happy with my blacklist workaround.  I just thought it was an odd error, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes my whole PHP response was a bunch of hex codes like this.

I had that when `opcache.fast_shutdown="1"` was set.